# Leave-class of Vue transition on <slot/> not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, css-transitions, tailwind-css

I have a `default-layout` component of which the `transition` works, but only half of it. The transition consists of two parts, one `enter` and one `leave` transition. Problem is that it only shows the `enter` transition. When a new `slot` component is rendered, the transition starts at `opacity: 100%` and transitions to `0%`. The `leave` transition that is supposed to go from `opacity: 0%` to `100%` first, is not shown at all.

Here's **`default-layout.vue`**:

```
<template>
  <div class="bg-slate-900">
    <c-header/>
    <transition
      mode="out-in"
      appear-from-class="opacity-0"
      leave-to-class="opacity-0"
      appear-active-class="transition duration-1000"
      leave-active-class="transition duration-1000" appear>
      <slot/>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>
```

This is how `default-layout` is placed in for example the **`index.vue`** component:

```
<template>
  <default-layout>
    
    // ...

  </default-layout>
</template>
```

First I had no `appear` property on the transition, which prevented it entirely from working. After reading [Transition not working for slots in vue 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68516014/transition-not-working-for-slots-in-vue-3) I've added the `appear` prop which made half of the transition work at least.

How would I make the `leave` part of the transition work as well?